# How do I show different components depending on device (web or mobile)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

With my Angular 7 web app, using TypeScript, bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, etc, how do I switch between components depending on what device the user is on (desktop vs mobile)?

I see lots of sites that show different components when I resize!
I'm not sure if these are the same responsive components just with lots of fancy css, but it some cases it seems like they are entirely different components.

Ex. YouTube desktop vs mobile (non native)

Comment: `ngIf`. [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). But, why are you using Bootstrap then? It's made for responsive layouts.

Comment: It just seems like there are better ways to determine device other than screen size, I just don't know how. Ex. determining device then rendering specific component for that device, instead of rendering two components and displaying/hiding with media queries

Comment: It looks like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-responsive shows/hides items based on device, but it still has to render everything. I thought there would be a more efficient way to determine device then only select that component to render

Comment: Well. In Angular, you define nested components in the component markup. You still have to render your entire markup for all possible devices. Then, you need to hide unnecessary components using `ngIf`. Otherwise, you need to create components in code. Alternatively, you can put your business logic in a library and create several UI applications for each device.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **ngx-device-detector** and detect the device you're using:

```
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';

this.deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
const isMobile = this.deviceService.isMobile();
const isTablet = this.deviceService.isTablet();
const isDesktopDevice = this.deviceService.isDesktop();
```